# Rails : How to put I18N into SVG file

Tags: ruby, svg

I want to internationalize several SVG files but I have no idea how I could do that.
Here's my SVG file :

```
<text font-family="OpenSans-Semibold, Open Sans" font-size="22" font-weight="500" fill="#FFFFFF">
  <tspan x="39" y="157">Accessoires</tspan>
</text>
```

Should I do something like :

```
<text font-family="OpenSans-Semibold, Open Sans" font-size="22" font-weight="500" fill="#FFFFFF">
  <tspan x="39" y="157"><%= t('accessoires') %></tspan>
</text>
```

Or is there an other way to do it ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @RobertLongson what kind of joke is that ?

Answer (score 0):

I know three ways to build svg with parameter. The first one is save it as string and then call `html_safe`. The second way use object tag according to W3C [SVG with parameters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/)

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="text.svg" class="logo">
  <param text="<%= t('accessoires') %>">
</object>

<text font-family="OpenSans-Semibold, Open Sans" font-size="22" font-weight="500" fill="#FFFFFF">
  <tspan x="39" y="157" content-value="param(label)" />
</text>
```

Third way is use raw svg or partial `_my_svg.html.erb`:

```
<text font-family="OpenSans-Semibold, Open Sans" font-size="22" font-weight="500" fill="#FFFFFF">
  <tspan x="39" y="157" content-value="<%= t('accessoires') %>" />
</text>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but what do you mean by save it as string and call ```html_safe``` ? Should it looks like ```<tspan x="39" y="157">t('Accessoires')</tspan>.html_safe``` ?

Comment: It should be `"<svg><tspan x="39" y="157">#{t('Accessoires')}</tspan></svg>".html_safe`. You need to interpolate I18n to string before converting to html.

Comment: I think best way is third. You create partial (html.erb file) where you copy your svg code and just add erb code where you need.

Comment: Should I create the partial into the same folder ? In ``app/assets/images ``` ? 
But how do I add erb code ? I tried to do the way you explained to me but do not seems to work...

Comment: You don't need to save svg to assets. Create file `_accessoires.html.erb` in `views/layouts` folder. Then you can use your svg by adding to view `<%= render 'layouts/accessoires' %>`